# how to get payerid in execute payment

Tags: paypal

i'm trying to implement an execute payment method for a paypal credit card payment.

according to the docs paypal sends a discardable token, and the payerid to my url, however, how do I know the payerid to begin with?  I created a payment for a user logged into my site and the user is then redirected to pp for confirmation.  That works fine, but I only know the user with my own internal user id, i.e. I don't know the pp payerid.

my createpayment method comes straight out of the rest api documentation with my data substituted for the hc data.

Answer (score 0):

You won't know the payerid until the buyer has logged into the PayPal account on the PayPal checkout page.  Once the buyer is redirected back to your return URL, PayPal sends back the payerid.  You will want to link the returning buyer to their order by using the discardable token.  Since you have the token before you send the buyer to PayPal, you will assign that token to the buyers order on your database.  That way, when the buyer returns, you have the token to use to reference the order, and the payerid to use in the execute payment call.  The you get the token after the create payment call in the approval url:
`"href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-50U50789A25920031",`

You shouldn't need to log the payerid for anything long term, since the same buyer may use another PayPal account on their next transaction with you.